# Are Poisson integrals uniquely determined by their radial limits?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integral-transforms, harmonic-functions

Let $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on the unit circle, and suppose its Poisson integral $u$ satisfies $\lim_{r\to 1-}u(re^{i\theta})=0$ for every $\theta$. Does it follow that $\mu=0$?

This is of course true if $\mu\geq 0$, but the usual proof has no obvious extension to signed measures. On the other hand, there are nonzero harmonic functions in the unit disc whose radial limits are $0$, but I don't know of one that is a Poisson integral.